# алгоритм выделения параметров из командной строки

Tags: c, алгоритм, символы, командная-строка

Задача состоит в следующем:

Командная строка будет содержать только следующие символы:
∙ латинские буквы (большие и маленькие) и цифры,
∙ пробел (ASCII 32),
∙ двойные кавычки (ASCII 34).

Параметры записываются в командную строку подряд в порядке следования. Между
каждыми двумя соседними параметрами вставляется один или несколько пробелов, чтобы
отделить их друг от друга. Параметр может быть целиком заключён в двойные кавычки.
Если внутри параметра есть пробелы, он заключён в двойные кавычки обязательно. Символов двойных кавычек в самих параметрах нет — ими лишь можно окружать параметры.
Все параметры непустые.

Командная строка, которую необходимо разобрать, записана в единственной строке входного файла. Её длина не превышает 100 символов. Учтите, что в этой командной строке
отсутствует имя исполняемого файла. В выходной файл нужно вывести искомые параметры
командной строки, по одному параметру в строке. Каждый параметр должен быть заключён в квадратные скобки. Особый нулевой параметр (саму командную строку) выводить не
нужно.

---

*далее мой код. Он вроде как нормально работает, но при вводе более одного пробела на выходе какая-то непонятная каша, и я не могу понять в чем причина:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        switch (c) {
        case '"':
            printf("[");
            scanf("%c", &c);

            while (c != '"')
            {
                printf("%c", c);
                scanf("%c", &c);
            }
            //printf("]\n");
        case ' ':
            if (c != '\n')
            {
                scanf("%c", &c);
            }
        default:
            while (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
            {
                printf("[%c", c);
                scanf("%c", &c);
            }
            printf("]\n");
    
            getch();
        }
    } while ( c!= '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

пример ввода-вывода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: UPD:когда не введено ни одного пробела, тоже получается каша

Comment: Простейший конечный автомат...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет "каши" не понял, но пару ошибок в алгоритме нашел:

1. Под конец каждого `case` нужно писать `break`
2. Комментарий `//printf("]\n");` раскомментируйте, полезная строчка)
3. `case ' '` не понял почему он такой у вас, можно просто пропустить пробел написав `break`.
4. В `default` перед циклом печатать `[` а внутри цикла символы, а не каждую итерацию `[%c`.
5. `getch()` тоже не понял зачем он тут.

Полный измененный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    do {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        switch (c) {
        case '"':
            printf("[");
            scanf("%c", &c);
            while (c != '"') {
                printf("%c", c);
                scanf("%c", &c);
            }
            printf("]\n");
            break;
        case ' ':
            break;
        default:
            printf("[");
            while (c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
                printf("%c", c);
                scanf("%c", &c);
            }
            printf("]\n");
        }
    } while (c != '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Результат программы:

[image: Результат]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы немного переписал ваше решение как то так (код на C#)

```
public List<string> GetParameters(string input)
{
    var result = new List<string>();    
    int ind = 0; 
    
    while(ind < input.Length)
    {       
        while(ind < input.Length && input[ind] == ' ') ind++;
        if (ind == input.Length) break;
        
        int start = ind;
        ind++;
        if (input[start] == '"')
        {
            while(ind < input.Length && input[ind] != '"') ind++;
            result.Add(input.Substring(start + 1, ind - start-1));
        }
        else 
        {
            while(ind < input.Length && input[ind] != ' ') ind++;
            result.Add(input.Substring(start, ind - start));
        }           
        ind++;      
    }   
    
    return result;  
}
```

Проверка

```
GetParameters("\"abc d\" e").Dump();
GetParameters("\"long p \" \"p 2\" \"sht\"   s   pars").Dump();
```

Результат

[image: ...]

Answer (score 1):

У вас в задании написано: "Командная строка будет содержать только следующие символы: ∙ латинские буквы (большие и маленькие) и цифры, ∙ пробел (ASCII 32), ∙ двойные кавычки (ASCII 34)". Также запрещены кавычки внутри параметров и пустые параметры. Эти ограничения нужно учесть.

В общем, вот вариант, на мой взгляд гораздо более корректный (хоть может и не идеальный), т.к. осуществляет разбор с учётом возможных ошибок синтаксиса входной строки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1023

void InitCharMap();

enum STATE:char
{
    STATE_SEARCH_PARAM,
    STATE_IN_PARAM,
    STATE_IN_QUOT_PARAM,
    STATE_OUT_QUOT_PARAM,
    STATE_BREAK
};

enum CHAR_TYPE:char
{
    CHAR_FORBIDDEN = 0,
    CHAR_EOL,
    CHAR_SPACE,
    CHAR_QMARK,
    CHAR_SYMBOL
};

char g_CharMap[256] = {0};


int main()
{
    char szInput[MAX_LEN+1];
    STATE state = STATE_SEARCH_PARAM;

    InitCharMap();

    fputs("Enter the input string:> ",stdout);
    fgets(szInput,MAX_LEN+1,stdin);

    char* p = szInput;
    while (state!=STATE_BREAK)
    {
        char c = *(p++);
        char ct = g_CharMap[c];

        if (ct==CHAR_FORBIDDEN)
        {
            printf("\nERROR: forbiden character: '%c'\n",c);
            break;
        }

        switch (state)
        {
        case STATE_SEARCH_PARAM:
            switch(ct)
            {
            case CHAR_SPACE:
                continue;
            case CHAR_EOL:
                state = STATE_BREAK;
                continue;
            case CHAR_QMARK:
                putchar('[');
                state = STATE_IN_QUOT_PARAM;
                continue;
            default: //case CHAR_SYMBOL:
                putchar('[');
                putchar(c);
                state = STATE_IN_PARAM;
            }
            continue;

        case STATE_IN_PARAM:
            switch (ct)
            {
            case CHAR_SYMBOL:
                putchar(c);
                continue;
            case CHAR_SPACE:
                puts("]");
                state = STATE_SEARCH_PARAM;
                continue;                       
            case CHAR_EOL:
                puts("]");
                state = STATE_BREAK;
                continue;
            default: //case CHAR_QMARK:
                printf("\nERROR: the quotation mark is not allowed in param!\n");
                state = STATE_BREAK;
            }
            continue;

        case STATE_IN_QUOT_PARAM:
            switch (ct)
            {
            case CHAR_QMARK:
                puts("]");
                if (g_CharMap[*(p-2)]==CHAR_QMARK)
                {
                    printf("\nERROR: empty param!\n");
                    state = STATE_BREAK;
                    continue;
                }
                state = STATE_OUT_QUOT_PARAM;
                continue;
            case CHAR_EOL:
                printf("\nERROR: unexpected end of line!\n");
                state = STATE_BREAK;
                continue;
            default:
                putchar(c);
            }
            continue;

        default: //case STATE_OUT_QUOT_PARAM:
            switch (ct)
            {
            case CHAR_SPACE:
                state = STATE_SEARCH_PARAM;
                continue;
            case CHAR_EOL:
                state = STATE_BREAK;
                continue;
            default:
                printf("\nERROR: missing space between params!\n");
                state = STATE_BREAK;
            }
            continue;
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}


void InitCharMap()
{
    g_CharMap[0] = CHAR_EOL;
    g_CharMap[0xA] = CHAR_EOL;
    g_CharMap[0xD] = CHAR_EOL;

    g_CharMap[9] = CHAR_SPACE;
    g_CharMap[0x20] = CHAR_SPACE;

    g_CharMap['"'] = CHAR_QMARK;

    for (char i=0x30; i<=0x39; ++i) g_CharMap[i] = CHAR_SYMBOL;
    for (char i='A'; i<='Z'; ++i) g_CharMap[i] = CHAR_SYMBOL;
    for (char i='a'; i<='z'; ++i) g_CharMap[i] = CHAR_SYMBOL;
}
```